# Train keras ResNet50V2 with 16-bit images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, resnet

I have 3-channel tif-images (16-bit).
Now, I would like to use them as training images on the pretrained ResNet50V2 from keras. I understood, that I should call the `tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input` as preprocessing function when using ImageDataGenerators. I looked up the documentation of the function ([preprocess_input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet_v2/preprocess_input?hl=de)) and it tells me at least that it expects 8-bit data.
Is there any way to give the 16-bit images to the ImageDataGenerator?

Or do I have to convert my images to 8-bit before feeding them to the ImageDataGenerator?

I'm happy for any advice!

Comment: I edited your question so it focuses on one question only, as per the site guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reference to 8-bit data in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet_v2/preprocess_input?hl=de) you linked.

And yes, it can accept 16-bit:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 256, (1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.uint16)

tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input(x)
```

```
array([[[[ 0.43529415, -0.24705881, -0.23137254],
         [-0.81960785,  0.3411765 , -0.5921569 ],
         [-0.7882353 ,  0.58431375,  0.0196079 ],
         ...,
         [-0.60784316, -0.4980392 ,  1.        ],
         [-0.654902  ,  0.99215686, -0.38039213],
         [ 0.03529418, -0.7411765 , -0.8901961 ]]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: The documentation says for argument 'x': A floating point numpy.array or a tf.Tensor, 3D or 4D with 3 color channels, with values in the range [0, 255]. The preprocessed data are written over the input data if the data types are compatible. To avoid this behaviour, numpy.copy(x) can be used.

Comment: I guess, I should have mentioned that my images have values of the full 16-bit range (0,65535)

Comment: Divide them by 65535?

Comment: But then they are still not using the range of [0,255]. And I do not know at all, what this preprocessing function is supposed to do - rescaling from -1 to 1? If that's it, I would have to rescale the images to [0,255] before. But at which point is that possible?

Comment: Divide by 65535 then multiply by 255

Comment: But the ImageDataGenerator has to do that as it loads the images. Would the ```rescale``` parameter help? Is the image rescaled before preprocessing?